# compile concurrently, link serially

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, linker

I have big cmake/c++/linux project: a lot of small static libraries, a few big and interdependent static libraries, a few big executable binaries. Single binary with debug symbols is several GB. There are ~10 such binaries (worker, testA, testB, testC...). Compilation usually takes more time than we would like, but we have fast build server and we use `make -j20`. The worst though is linking. Single linking takes about 60 seconds and 4GB RAM. But when all final binaries are linked at the same time (happens often when 1 small sublibrary was modified, little to recompile, a lot to relink), 10 linkers use 40GB RAM (for 1 developer, there may be more) and very long time. IO is most likely the bottleneck.

We have many developers on 1 strong server and everybody uses `make -j20 -l30` so that we don't overload CPU. But we don't have method for limiting number of concurrent linkers. It would be great to limit number of working linkers globally on server, but per make invocation would help as well. Ideally `make -j20 -l30 --concurrent-linkers=2`. Is it possible?

We use gold linker. We are in progress of separating smaller, independent modules, but this will take a long time.

Comment: The problem is that `make` itself doesn't really know what's happening, all it does is execute commands without knowing what the commands are really doing.

Comment: As a possible workaround you could use two targets: One for compilation and one for linking. The compilation target is run using high parallelization and the linking target without.

Comment: I might be missing the point. Using less linkers isn't going to make linking faster, is it? You'll get the first output quicker, but the last link will start much later and finish at the same time as before (assuming you do have enough RAM, of course).

Comment: @MSalters We have basically thin clients to central server.  When linkers start abusing server, nobody can work due to overloaded IO. Secondly, we have 2nd server with less RAM - it can compile -j30 no problem, but linking -j4 causes OOM killer

Comment: Are you restricted to `make`? CMake can also target Ninja, and Ninja supports [JOB_POOL_LINK](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/JOB_POOL_LINK.html#prop_tgt:JOB_POOL_LINK)

Comment: @MSalters Thanks, this looks very much like what I need. We are currently restricted to make because project doesn't compile on Ninja (don't know why). We have low priority task to fix it, but this may be the reason to upgrade the priority :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
$ cat Makefile
OBJS := foo bar baz...
EXES := qux quux quuz...

.PHONY: all

all: $(OBJS)
    $(MAKE) -j $(concurrent-linkers) $(EXES)

$(OBJS): ...
    <compile>

$(EXES): ...
    <link>
```

And call it with:

```
$ make -j20 -l30 concurrent-linkers=2
```

Basically, it separates the build in two make invocations, one for compilation and one for link, with different `-j` options. The main drawback is that all compilations must be finished before the first link starts. A better solution would be to design a simple link job server (a simple shell script with a bit of `flock` and tag files would make it) and delegate it the link jobs. But if you can live with this...

Demo with a dummy Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
OBJS := a b c d e f
EXES := u v w x y z

.PHONY: all

all: $(OBJS)
    $(MAKE) -j $(concurrent-linkers) $(EXES)

$(OBJS) $(EXES):
    @printf 'building $@...\n' && sleep 2 && printf 'done\n' && touch $@
$ make -j20 -l30 concurrent-linkers=2
building a...
building d...
building b...
building c...
building e...
building f...
done
done
done
done
done
done
make -j 2 u v w x y z
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
make[1]: Entering directory 'foobar'
building u...
building v...
done
done
building w...
building x...
done
done
building y...
building z...
done
done
make[1]: Leaving directory 'foobar'
```

As you can see all `$(OBJS)` targets are built in parallel while the `$(EXES)` targets are built 2 (maximum) at a time.

**EDIT** If your makefile is generated by CMake there are at least two options:

1. Tune your CMake files such that CMake generates two different makefiles: one for compilation and one for link. Then write a simple wrapper makefile like:

   ```
   .PHONY: myAll myCompile

   myAll: myCompile
       $(MAKE) -j $(concurrent-linkers) -f Makefile.link

   myCompile:
       $(MAKE) -f Makefile.compilation
   ```
2. Convince CMake (if it is not already the case) to generate a makefile that defines two make variables: one (`OBJS`) set to the list of all object files and one (`EXES`) set to the list of all executable. Then write a simple wrapper makefile like:

   ```
   .DEFAULT_GOAL := myAll

   include CMake.generated.Makefile

   .PHONY: myAll

   myAll: $(OBJS)
       $(MAKE) -j $(concurrent-linkers) $(EXES)
   ```

   A very similar solution exists if, instead, CMake generates two phony targets, one for all object files and the other for all executable:

   ```
   .DEFAULT_GOAL := myAll

   include CMake.generated.Makefile

   .PHONY: myAll

   myAll: cmake-target-for-compilation
       $(MAKE) -j $(concurrent-linkers) cmake-target-for-link
   ```

Comment: The `Makefile` in the question is generated by CMake; this answer presumes a hand-rolled Makefile.

Comment: MSalters is correct - is it possible to do with CMake?

Comment: If you can use CMake to generate two makefiles, one for compilation and one for link, then yes, it is possible (and easy). Else, you must find a way to tell CMake that you want a makefile that defines a make variable set to all object files and another set to all executable. You will then simply include this CMake-generated makefile in a wrapper makefile that does more or less what I suggest in my examples.